# MySQL view populated using functios is too slow. Is my design faulty?

Tags: mysql, function, view

I have a view in my database called users_ranks where the columns are populated using functions

[image]

The following is an example of the function retrieving the user hobbies

[image]

The view use the functions in the following way

[image]

The problem is that the view is so slow that crashes the app using the data. Is my design flawed?

Comment: Why are you doing this? It runs at least 12 extra SELECT queries _for each row_ of `users` that you query via this view.

Comment: For this I'll create a table as with all the calculated fields, then consume that table.

Comment: Hi Bill, that's why I have asked the question. To take advises from someone more expert than me in this field. So apart the redundant question have you got any suggestion? Maybe small code sample. Thank you.